# Pyinstaller exe file doesn't take any input

Tags: python, numpy, exe, pyinstaller, executable

I want to create .exe file from .py. If I run .py file it works well and I have no problem with it. But when I run .exe file created by pyinstaller I can not input(type) anything in command line.

I have tried a several options already - onefile execuatable(--onefile), disable upx(--noupx). Both give no improvements at all.

Is it a problem that I importing my own libs? Better to paste functions I use inside my .py file?

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from convetai.cropImage import cropImage, step
def main():
    path = input()
    img = np.array(Image.open(f"{path}"))

    print("Your image has a shape of ", img.shape)
    n = int(input("Enter number of divisions."))
    #dx, dy = step(n, img.shape)
    i = int(input("Enter num of row"))
    j = int(input("Enter num of column"))
    n_img = cropImage(img, n, i, j, save=True)
    print("Done.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank You.

Comment: you run one windows make sure you declare the program to be a console program as it seems to expect userinput.

So don't forget the switch `--console`

Also start with the onedir `-D` option. Only if you get it work with the onedir option you should continue with the `--onefile` 

perhaps add a print statement before 
`path = input()`

and use perhaps:
`path = input("please enter the path")` 
for better debugging.
And tell us exactly what you see on your consoel after these changes

Comment: No changes at all when I type `pyinstaller --onedir --console script.py`. I run dist\script\script.exe file which opens cmd for half of second and then close it. I also added `path = input("Enter the path")`.

Comment: don't click on the exe for debugging (except you are a very fast reader ;-) )
open a cmd window and call the exe from there.
This gives you time to read the error message, which you can then post here

Comment: Oh, it says `No module named 'numpy.random.common'`

Comment: Solved by adding `import numpy.random.common
import numpy.random.bounded_integers
import numpy.random.entropy`. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since there is ***input()*** method you should use the console option when converting to exe file. GUI will not work. try the code below

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console test_Script.py
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me. Is there a way to add the file name with spaces like 'test 001.py'

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use pyinstaller to make exe and whenever you need input in your program, just use tkinter.

Example:

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
for features in FeatureList:

```
ROOT = tk.Tk()

ROOT.withdraw()
# the input dialog
USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="User Input",
                                  prompt="Do You want to Continue")
# check it out
print("Continuing", USER_INP)
```

Now you can use USER_INP in whatever fasion you want